# How to get another component when I click h1 tag in react using hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react project in that project Home.js is Parent component and Test.js is Child component. In Home.js component I have  tag here what I am trying to do is If I Click  tag I need to call Test.js component. For this In Home.js I created one function and, To that function I passed Test.js component. and I passed that function via onClick method to h1 tag but its not working. How to achieve this.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from "./Pages/Home/Home";
import Test from "./Pages/Test/Test";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'><Home></Home></Route>
          <Route path='/test'><Test></Test></Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                            <ul className="navbar-nav">
                                <li className="nav-item active">
                                    <Link className='nav-link' to='/'>Home</Link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Test from '../Test/Test';

export default function Home() {
    const Test = () => {
        <Test></Test>
    }
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div>
                        <h1 onClick={Test}>Cruse</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is Test.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Test() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Test works</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is in your function definition. you should use js or jquery to add element to your body like:
```const Test = () => {
       document.getElementByTagName("H1")[0].appendChild(<Test></Test>); 
    }```
I haven't tested this let me know if it is correct or not

Comment: Hi @ShaahinShemshian, I tried your code but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are using event handlers wrong. Their purpose is to produce some kind of side effects, and they don't return a direct result. If you wish to show new element on click i recommend using react state and something like this:

```
 export default function Home() {
    const [isTestVisible, setTestVisible] = useState(false);
    const showTest= () => setTestVisible(true);       

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div>
                        <h1 onClick={showTest}>Cruse</h1>
                        {isTestVisible && <Test />}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

In your state you could save different props for each test component so you can customize them. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi @Kaca992, If some click <h1> tag in the Home.js then I have to show Test.js component. For suppose I clicked <h1> tag in the Home.js, then it have to redirect to Test.js component  but I don't want to use <Link> tag in react.

Comment: If you only want to show this element on click then you can change it to use a flag. When you click Test will be rendered and appended as a child to you h1 element.

Answer (score 0):

Using states is the correct answer as @Kaca992 said. But for what you do, you can do something like this:

```
const Test = () => {
        ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]);
    }
```